# How do you Change a type from one to another in Ada?

Tags: types, ada

I am confused about changing types in Ada.  Specifically receiving user input, which is stored as a string, and then performing operations on it as a float or integer. My goal is to make a table of logarithms based on a users start and stop points, incrementing by any value they want. I have tried something such as:  Start := Float'Image(Start); I could you some help, thanks.

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Float_Text_IO, Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;
use  Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Float_Text_IO, Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions;

procedure log_table is

   Start, Stop, Increment, temp : Float; 

begin                                           -- Prompt for input
   Put_Line("To print a table of logarithms,");
   Put(" enter the start, stop, and increment values: ");
   Get(Start); Get(Stop); Get(Increment);

   loop 
    exit when (Start > Stop);
    Put("The logarithm of");
    Put(Start);
    Put(" is ");
    Put_Line( log(Start, 10.0) );
    Start := Start + Increment;
   end loop;

end log_table;
```

So the code now runs... I will post the changed portion of code below.  All I did was change the Put_Line function to a Put function and then added a New_Line function after.  Any reason why this works? From my understanding the only difference between Put_Line and Put is that is adds a '\n' to the end. A better understanding would be appreciated.

```
   loop 
    exit when (Start > Stop);
    Put("The logarithm of ");
    Put(Start);
    Put(" is ");
    Put( log(Start, 10.0));
    New_Line;
    Start := Start + Increment;
   end loop;
```

Comment: Do yourself the favour of reading the specification of the packages you are using.  If you remove the `use` clause, and insert the full names of the subprograms you call, you might also learn a bit.

Comment: It's really simple, Put_Line doesn't exist for Real types as stated in the [ARM](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-9.html)

Comment: Put_Line does not add '\n' to the end. ('\n' is a syntax error in Ada.) If you Put a String containing "\n", you'll get the 2 characters '\' and 'n' in your output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you convert from one type to another using the name of the target type as if it was a function name:

```
 A := Some_Integer_Type (3.41);
```

But this only works for compatible types.  Arrays (such as strings) and numerical types are never compatible, so you are most likely looking for [LRM 3.5(52)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-5.html#p52).